# System-wide equalizer for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, equalizer

Is there any system-wide equalizer for Ubuntu 13.10?. A few months ago I had 12.04 and used pusleaudio equalizer. But now it is not working for saucy and I tried the alsa equalizer but I do not see any results.

I know that this question has been answered several times, but I have not found an answer for 13.10.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

This worked for me on 13.10.

[PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) is another solution (works on 17.04).

```
sudo apt-get install pulseeffects
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html worked for me, but it was super buggy.  Maybe it will work better with your sound card.

Comment: I have already tried this solution and it has not worked for me. Also I saw a comment in the article requesting to create a PPA for 13.10.