# Is there an equalizer in the BASE Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound, equalizer

Is there an equalizer in the BASE (that is not PPA) Ubuntu 14.04?

(I have PulseAudio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 in the repositories for specific soune systems:

Alsa:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugin-equal
```

[image]

---

LV2:

```
sudo apt-get install eq10q
```

[image]

For pulse you are bound to be needing a PPA. Link to some PPA's (in case you change your mind ;) ):

- [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)
- [System-wide equalizer for Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363741/system-wide-equalizer-for-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: How do I know which of the three sound systems I'm using?

Comment: 99%: pulse... `ps -ef | grep pulse` ;)

Comment: @MaxB power of the masses. If they where the 1st user that knows how to detect a trojan will alarm any other user.

Comment: It looks like my last comment got censored (I did not delete it)

Comment: the last time I checked, you usually ran pulse "on top off" alsa. So you run both (probably)